# How to find peak power at 1550nm using an optical meter?

Tags: optics, laser, power, signal-processing, fiber-optics

I have a setup of tunable laser source at 1550nm connected to a spectrometer(Can't publish the name of spectrometer). The spectrometer has a range of 1510-1595 nm. The graph shows wavelength vs amplitude. The amplitude is in terms of intensity which is not an standard unit.

I am trying to convert the amplitude in terms of dBm or watts. Something like a table amplitude and its equivalent dBm. I have an optical meter but the value shown in optical meter is average power. I have to find the amplitude at 1550nm alone. I have an another optical spectrum analyzer(old model from Agilent)using which I could see the entire spectrum with power at each frequency (in terms of dBm).

I can have that as reference but I want to find the **mathematical way** of finding the peak power at 1550nm alone given the **spectrum diagram** like shown below and an optical meter which could tell me the **average power**.[image]

INFO: I can vary the power of TLS from -6dBm to -10dBm.

Edit 1: Is there any way to use a tunable laser source to produce a laser pulse with peak power of X dBm (Say -5 dBm) at 1550nm? In general the power we set at tunable laser source, is that integrated power or peak power?

Comment: By average power you mean RMS power? P(rms)=Ppeak/sqrt2

Comment: The average power(as used in wiki) on the context of optical meter means the power received at a range of frequency from the laser source (example 1500 to 1600nm). In clear terms we could call it integrated power as mentioned by Gilbert

Answer (score 1):

The y-axis shows the number of counts.

Divide the peak power value measured with your watt meter with the number of counts shown in the above spectrogtaph to find the resolution per count e.g. 3W/14400 counts ===>  208.3μW/(one count).

If you watt meter shows not peak power but instead *RMS average power* then multiply its reading with √2 to find P(peak).

Use an automatic tool like this [here](https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/power/Watt_to_dBm.html) to find corresponding dBm values (be warned dBm units are used usually for indicating average RMS power and not peak power. If you must so, then you have to indicate this that it is dBm(peak) values).

Comment: Thank you for answering . But the optical meter gives integrated power which can't be compare with amplitude at one particular wavelength. 
Do you suggest any mathematical way to convert the integrated power to power at each wavelength using the shape of spectrum?

Comment: For such a sharp resonance peak power is practically the same with integrated power. For even better results use a higher Q monochromatic laser.

Comment: As far I can see in your plot your laser has a spectrum no more than 2nm wide. The error will be practically zero. Nevertheless, you can always amend the uncertainty value  percentage in your measurements

Answer (score 1):

Likely your power meter is showing you the integrated power, i.e. all the power in your laser beam, including all frequencies. So integrate the counts measured by your spectrometer and call that $C$. Then if your power measurement is $P$ (in whatever units), the ratio $P/C$ is the scaling factor for your spectrum.

Keep in mind that you can’t measure a power at *exactly* 1550 nm; it’ll always be with regard to some bandwidth, limited by the resolution of your system.

Comment: Do you mean to find the bandwidth of optical meter. And find the sum of amplitude of spectrometer in all wavelength within the bandwidth of optical meter and consider as C.

Comment: @KishoreKumarS no, your power meter measures everything, so add up all the counts in your entire spectrum, and that’s C. You could have a much broader spectrum, for example, in which case it would clearly not be instrument limited. Your spectrum is so narrow that it indeed may be instrument limited (i.e. the laser spectrum could be narrower than you can resolve). In this case, there is no point in doing this calculation; all the power is at the center wavelength (as far as you instruments can tell).

Comment: @KishoreKumarS one thing I forgot is that since your spectrometer is reporting counts (a linear scale), you should convert to Watts (also a linear scale). Afterward, you can convert to dBm (log scale) if you wish.